# Integrating with different methods leads to different results?

Tags: integration, proof-verification

Acceleration of a particle is given as $a = 0.1(t-5)^2$. The particle is initially at rest.

Here is the way I initially attempted it. (I didn't use substitution as the question in the textbook appears before substitution is officially taught.)

$$a\:=\:0.1t^2-t+2.5$$
so 
$$v  = \frac{1}{30}t^3-0.5t^2+2.5t+c$$
$c$  evaluates to zero.

But my textbook uses a substitution and gets:

$$\frac{1}{30}\left(t-5\right)^3 +c$$

In this case, c has a value when t= 0 and so the end result is different. Wouldn't this lead to different values in general?

Comment: No it won't. The constants will always adjust accordingly to make the results match in the end.

Comment: The values of your $c$ and the answer’s $c$ will be different, but that’s just because their answer also has a constant term in the polynomial expression. The total combined constant term in their answer ($\tfrac1{30}(-5)^3+c$) will be the same as yours, namely, $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you ended up with
$$
v(t) = \frac{1}{30} t^3 - \frac12 t^2 + \frac52 t
$$

But the book's answer must have $c = 5^3/30$, so the complete answer is
$$
\begin{split}
v(t) &= \frac{1}{30} (t-5)^3 + \frac{5^3}{30}\\
     &= \frac{(t-5)^3-5^3}{30} \\
     &= \frac{t^3 - 3\cdot 5 t^2 + 3 \cdot 5^2t - 5^3 + 5^3}{30} \\
     &= \frac{t^3}{30} - \frac{t^2}{2} + \frac{5t}{2}\\
\end{split}
$$
which is the same answer as the one you ended up with.